# Best way to show navigation details for more than one destination

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation

I am working on a navigation program for the Android, and one feature is to allow you to enter several destinations, and it will show directions on how to get from point A to point B to point C.

My difficulty is showing the details, as I am not certain the best choices to use.

Basically what I want to do is to show the top level detail, so you can see going to Point B and how many miles/minutes is estimated, but if there are several of these listed, as `TextView` components, would it be a simple move to the right to show all the details of that part of the trip, and move the left to show the top view of each destination?

I hope this makes sense, basically, I want to just show the address/travel time/distance to each waypoint, but then give the user an intuitive way to see the details of that part of the trip.

I am developing this for Android 2.3, btw.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer using the google maps treeview listing on the journey details and the estimated time listed as the heading of the treeview.

But i do understand that you would like to change the destination view details such that each journey details are listed on the right.

like 
 Point A to B  blah,blah,blah
               blah,blah,blah
 Point B to C  blah,blah,blah

For this i suggest you make a custom view so that you will have more flexibility in designing the layout according to your needs
I hope this answers your question, btw i am only a junior android developer..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I may need to go with a custom view, but I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Glad to help maybe if your application is not a proprietary maybe you can show us how you resolved this.. tks

Comment: Once I decide on a good solution I will share the solution. :)